# Proper way to rollout GPO that requires restart of current and future machines?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Let's say I have a policy that sets specific encryption settings for our servers. We don't want SSL 3.0, insecure, ciphers, etc for example. After this change machines must be restarted for the changes to take affect.

1. existing machines should be restarted at specific time off hours
2. future machines will need to be restarted after policy is applied

What is the ideal approach for handling this situation where there is a set time that needs to be scheduled now, but also a restart that needs to occur for future machines (edit: and administrator won't know that is the case for the new machine)?

Answer (score 1):

GPOs don't reboot a system, so you need something else e.g. based on `shutdown -r`.

Future machines don't need that as they pull GPOs as soon as they've joined the domain (and were possibly moved to the appropriate OU). Usually, that's part of plattform installation where a machine is restarted a few times anyway.

Comment: Yes I would separate this from Group Policy. There either needs to be a Config Management or RMM tool. Or if all the hosts are local, just script it.